# How to create an annotation in Django that references two related models

Tags: django, django-annotate

I'm trying to add an annotation to a QuerySet that is True/False when the value of a field on one related object is less than the value of a field on a different related object.

Here are some models for an example:

```py
class RobotManager(models.Manager):
    queryset = super(RobotManager, self).get_queryset()
    queryset = queryset.annotate(canteen_empty=UNKNOWN CODE)
    return queryset

class Robot(models.Model):
    # Has some other unrelated stuff
    objects = RobotManager()

class CanteenLevel(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    robot = models.ForeignKey("SomeApp.Robot")
    gallons = models.IntegerField()

class RobotConfiguration(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    robot = models.ForeignKey("SomeApp.Robot")
    canteen_empty_level = models.IntegerField()
```

With the above models, as the Robot's Configuration or CanteenLevel change, we create new records and save the historicals.

What I would like to do is add an annotation to a Robot QuerySet that states if the Robot's Canteen is considered empty (Robot's latest CanteenLevel.gallons is less than the Robot's latest Configuration.canteen_empty_level).

The aim is to allow for a statement like this using the annotation in the QuerySet:

```py
bad_robots = Robot.objects.filter(canteen_empty=True)
```

I had tried something like this in the annotation:

```py
canteen_empty=ExpressionWrapper(CanteenLevel.objects.filter(robot=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-time').values('gallons')[:1] <= RobotConfiguration.objects.filter(robot=OuterRef('robot')).order_by('-time').values('canteen_empty_level')[:1], output_field=models.BooleanField))
```

But obviously the "<=" operator isn't allowed.

I also tried this:

```py
canteen_empty=Exists(CanteenLevel.objects.filter(robot=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-time').values('gallons')[:1].filter(gallons__lte=Subquery(RobotConfiguration.objects.filter(robot=OuterRef('robot')).order_by('-time').values('canteen_empty_level')[:1]))))
```

But you can't filter after taking a slice of a QuerySet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make two annotations here:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

latest_gallons = Subquery(CanteenLevel.objects.filter(
    robot=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-time').values('gallons')[:1])

latest_canteen = Subquery(RobotConfiguration.objects.filter(
    robot=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-time').values('canteen_empty_level')[:1])
```

then we can first annotate the `Robot` objects with these, and filter:

```
from django.db.models import F

Robot.objects.annotate(
    latest_gallons=latest_gallons,
    latest_canteen=latest_canteen
).filter(latest_gallons__lte=F('latest_canteen'))
```

This will construct a query that looks like:

```
SELECT robot.*,
    (SELECT U0.gallons
     FROM canteenlevel U0
     WHERE U0.robot_id = robot.id
     ORDER BY U0.time DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS latest_gallons,
    (SELECT U0.canteen_empty_level
     FROM robotconfiguration U0
     WHERE U0.robot_id = robot.id
     ORDER BY U0.time DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS latest_canteen
FROM robot
WHERE
    (SELECT U0.gallons
     FROM canteenlevel U0
     WHERE U0.robot_id = robot.id
     ORDER BY U0.time DESC
     LIMIT 1
    ) <= (
     SELECT U0.canteen_empty_level
     FROM robotconfiguration U0
     WHERE U0.robot_id = robot.id
     ORDER BY U0.time DESC
     LIMIT 1
    )
```

Note however that if a `Robot` has no related `CanteenLevel`, or `RobotConfiguration` (one of them, or both), then that `Robot` will *not* be included in the queryset.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and detailed response! This definitely gets me what I need.